# Finding error.type() then return the cell number not working with match?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to know how to return cell numbers for say #DIV/0!

```
ERROR.TYPE(#NULL!) = 1 
ERROR.TYPE(#DIV/0!) = 2
ERROR.TYPE(#VALUE!) = 3 etc
```

=if(text(O:O,#DIV/0!),"true", "false)") doesn't work
=match("ink",P:P,0), works (p25 = "ink")

=match("#DIV/0!",O:O,0) -> the error is [#N/A or "Did not find value '#DIV/0!' in MATCH evaluation."]

It sounds a bit confusing but I will clarify again if you don't understand

Comment: What is the content of O:O and P:P?

Comment: the content are formulas such as = 100/0, or anything that invokes an error, (does that make any sense???)

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

To look for #DIV/0! error,try

```
=MATCH(
   ERROR.TYPE(1/0),
   FILTER(ERROR.TYPE(O:O),LEN(IFERROR(O:O,ERROR.TYPE(O:O)))),
   0
 )
```

## Explanation

Google Sheets stops formula calculation if the formula founds an error as argument of a function that can't handle errors, so instead of looking for strings like "#DIV/0!", first calculate the error type, in this case for the O:O column, then search for the corresponding error type value.

The below formula part is used to return only the error type for non-blank and non-empty cells. IFERROR is used because LEN returns error for cells having an error as result.

```
FILTER(ERROR.TYPE(O:O),LEN(IFERROR(O:O,ERROR.TYPE(O:O))
```